# how to generate word from a to z

Tags: python, python-3.x

is it possible to create a method that generate a word from a to z ? cause i only know random generate word but what i want was a word that exist using python code

this is the random generate word code i have:

```
import random
wordLen = random.randint(1, 5)
def get_random_word(wordLen):
    word = ''

    for i in range(wordLen):
        word += random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    print(word)
    return word
get_random_word(wordLen)
```

or is it possible if i have a list of letter like example list= ['a','t','n','s','d','e','x'], then i want to generate real word from this list??

Comment: You would need access to a list of valid words to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Your code will create a random string of characters, I think. Do you want it to be picking real words? If so you probably need to use a word list, rather than creating the string it letter by letter.

Comment: okay but is it possible if i have a list of letter like example list= ['a','t','n','s','d','e','x'], then i want to generate real word from this list??

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like? **(untested)**:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice

words = defaultdict(list)
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fin:
    for word in fin:
        if len(word) == 5: 
            words.append(word)

for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    print letter, 'is for', choice(words[letter])
```

If you're not on a system that has `/usr/share/dict/words` (or you want a more comprehensive list), then http://www.findthatzip.com/search-10655738-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-ukacd16.zip.htm is reasonably okay aswell.

Comment: hey, it say FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/dict/words', then i download the file you put the link, but the directory how should i change?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need a list of words to choose from... once upon a time ago I needed one and I googled something like english dictionary txt... found a few and kept what looked the best to me

Then obviously you figure out how you're going to manage your list... infrequent use just read off the disk, maybe store the number of lines at the start of the file so you can select a number and read in only as far as you need...  Or store them in memory for frequent use, an array probably