# 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, dictionary

I encountered a problem with a code snippet that I'm trying to use. Here is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase
words = defaultdict(list)
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fin:
    for word in fin:
        if len(word) == 5: 
             words.append(word)
```

Whenever I try to run the code it returns the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'collections.defaultdict' has no attribute 'append'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you must append to `words`'s values not itself. like `words[key].append()`

Comment: You can't use `words.append()`, since it doesn't exist.  The correct code depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: YOu need some key, `words[key].append(word)`

Comment: still getting an error :/

Comment: @Freddy-FazBear, **which** error are you getting?!  Edit your Q to show the traceback.  By saying you're getting an error and **not** saying anything about which one and where it looks like you're trying to make it impossible for us to help you...!-)

Comment: sorry, XD. I just got it fixed, thanks though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict` is a type of dictionary; it does not have an `append` method.  That is only available on the `list` type.

Looking at your code, there is not really a reason for you to be using a dictionary-like structure.  Your goal is to collect individual items, not key/value pairs.  `words` should just be a list:

```
words = []
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fin:
    for word in fin:
        if len(word) == 5: 
            words.append(word)
```

---

Also, you probably want to call `str.rstrip()` on each line in order to remove the trailing newline:

```
for word in fin:
    word = word.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 4):

For clarification, your issue is that you're not setting a key for your .append()

When you instantiate your defaultdict(list) object, what you're doing is telling that dictionary-like object that each VALUE for a given KEY will be a list.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) for a more defined example / explanation.

Answer (score -1):

A `defaultdict` is just like a regular dictionary, except that, when you lookup the value of a key that isn't in the dictionary, it returns a default value instead of raising a `KeyError`.

It looks like you're using a code snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857529/how-to-generate-word-from-a-to-z). The original intent of that snippet was to group words by their first letter. Represented as a dictionary, the letters of the alphabet would be the keys, and lists of words would be the values. You want to append each word to the entry in the dictionary corresponding to the proper start letter.

If you're trying to achieve the same objective as that asker was, and you want to use a `defaultdict` for it, one way of proceeding would be to replace `words.append(word)` with `words[word[0]].append(word)`, or something to that effect.

If you're not trying to do the same, iCodez's answer is the way to go.

Comment: I never knew about the key part or what it does until now, and also sorry for no including the whole traceback error. This works also, thanks for the help and explanation. ;)